# Resources on Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm currently studying R.C. Walker's book on the subject which seems quite extensive and detailed. I've also been skimming through Hindman and Strauss's book *Algebra in the Stone-Čech Compactification: Theory and Applications*. Obviously they contain a large amount of citations to other books and research articles to have a glance at, but is there anything specific you would suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try Gillman and Jerison's book: Ring of continuous functions.
They explain the Stone-Čech compactification by continuous functions and filters (ultrafilter).